# on jquery submit data is being passed only once

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
function loadEditDialog(tag,event)
    {        
        event.preventDefault();       
        var $loading = $('<img src="../../Images/ajaxLoading.gif" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">');
        var $url = $(tag).attr('href');
       // var $url = $('<div> <input type="text" /></div>');
        var $title = $(tag).attr('title');
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>');
       // var $dialog = $('#diag');        
        $dialog.empty();
        $dialog
            .append($loading)
            .load($url)
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false
                , title: "Edit"
                , width: "310px"
                , modal: true
                , minHeight: 50
                , show: 'fade'
                , hide: 'fade'
                , buttons: {
                    "Cancel": function () {                       
                        $dialog.dialog('close');                        
                    },
                    "Submit": function () {
                        var editData = {
                            'DesignationId': $('#DesignationId').val(),
                            'DesignationName': $('#DesignationName').val()
                        };

                        var resultJSON = JSON.stringify(editData);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: $url,
                            type: "POST",
                            cache: false,
                            traditional: true,
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            data: resultJSON,
                            datatype: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert("Saved Successfully!!!");
                                $dialog.dialog('close');
                                clearpopup();
                                fillDesigGrid();
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {               
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }

            });

        $dialog.dialog('open');
    };
```

there is data in textbox it can be seen below image
[image]

but it is not getting passed in the array editData
[image: dfdfv]

the data is being passed for first hit after that either repeated values are going or blank if i clear values of textbox

[image]

the "property value" is showing actual value an "attribute value" is showing previous.
later "property value" goes blank even if values is there in text box

HTML for popup Edit

```
@model FullCalendar_MVC.DesignationMaster

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>DesignationMaster</legend>

        <div class="editor-label" hidden="hidden">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DesignationId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field" hidden="hidden">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DesignationId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DesignationId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">          
            Designation Name
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DesignationName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DesignationName)
        </div>       
        <div>

    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: If the fields are being cleared before you can use them then you should set them to variables when you do have the data and use those variables for the second call

Comment: "Submit": function () {
                        var editData = {                           
                        };
                       
                        editData.DesignationId = $('#DesignationId').val();;
                        editData.DesignationName = $('#DesignationName').val();
                        var resultJSON = JSON.stringify(editData);

Comment: i tried it with variables also but same problem.
it works for first time later for second time it gives above problem

Answer (score 0):

When the POST is success you are calling the method clearpopup(), if something is triggering the Submit method on your dialog after the first time, your fields maybe have been cleaned, for testing purpose, comment the call the clearpopup() on your "Success", just to verify that is not the issue.

Comment: check third image i have edited my ques
the "property value" is showing actual value an "attribute value" is showing previous.
later "property value" goes blank even if values is there in text box

Comment: could you add the Html with the inputs fields?

Comment: Try to isolate the code is failing. Basically the code on the sample i did here is not working: http://fiddle.jshell.net/eb4rmx95/

Comment: still i m using razor engine and html helper to create my controls. 
i hav edited the ques plz check